# Passing to listener

Tags: java, string, swing, awt, actionlistener

Is it possible to pass a `String` to an `ActionListener`? I'm creating a number guessing game, and I need to pass the difficulty selected to the the `ActionListener`, because it's passed from the first GUI opened. How would I do this as it's passed directly to the `Game()` constructor?

Comment: Why are there 2 GUIs and not one?  In any case, they should share a common GameModel, not pass Strings around.

Comment: @Nathan Kreider really what do you need, maybe there is/are another choices,

Answer (score 0):

Have your ActionListener access a variable that contains the result of the guess.

I would do something like:

```
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JButton button =new JButton("press");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String text = textArea.getText();
            if (text.equals("something")) {
                doSomething();
            } else {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the string come from? You can pass that component to the `ActionListener` when constructed. For example, your string comes from a `JLabel` object. Then

```
class GuessNumberActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel difficulty;

    public GuessNumberActionListener(JLabel difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    // implement other methods
}
```

Then inside your action listener, you can access/update what you want.

Answer (score 0):

ActionListener is an interface. try extending the functionality of the interface using inheritance. this will do the trick

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can. There are lots of ways but one of them is to pass it in to the the `ActionListener`'s constructor:

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener { 

    private int difficultyLevel;

    public MyClass(int difficultyLevel) {
      this.difficultyLevel = difficultyLevel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        ...//code that reacts to action and does something based on difficultyLevel
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

Looks like the design patterns police are out in full force today. You may want to quickly rewrite your app in MVC before you get shot in the foot :)

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/

Comment: Telling someone how to implement a bad idea does not help much.  If the user asked you how to shoot themselves in the foot, would you give instructions?

Comment: What's wrong with passing state to an action listener? Unless you read more into the question that was all I understood the OP was looking for.

Comment: And what would you do if all they were looking for was to produce a gaping hole in their foot?

Comment: Sounds like you are better informed in that subject than me.

Comment: My concern with the solution in this answer has nothing to do with holes in feet.  I'm not sure that constructing the action listener with a fixed difficultyLevel would work for the OP's question.  I'm not a fan of subclassing ActionListener, but if I did I would want to ensure that when the actionPerformed method was invoked, difficulty level was always current.

Comment: Noted and updated accordingly. Thank you for making stackoverflow a safer place for all of us.